# CSS: What is the defined behaviour for parent height:auto and children height:100%?

Tags: html, css, height

What is the defined behavior if the parent height is `auto` and 2 children with `height:100%` are placed below each other in it. For example:

```html
<html>
    <style>
        .cont {
            height: auto;
            background-color:silver;
        }
        .box {
            width:50px;
            height:100%;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="cont">
            <div class="box" style="background-color:yellow;"> a </div>
            <div class="box" style="background-color:red;"> b </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/kisvegabor/pen/XWXVQOX

In Chrome and Firefox the children are (more or less) screen-sized but in CodePen their height fits the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not given the HTML a DOCTYPE, so the normal CSS rules are modified by the page being rendered in quirks mode.

This effect you see is described in the [Quirks Mode Living Standard](https://quirks.spec.whatwg.org)

> #### [3.5. The percentage height calculation quirk](https://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/#the-percentage-height-calculation-quirk)
>
> In quirks mode, for the purpose of calculating the height of an
> element element, if the computed value of the position property of
> element is relative or static, the specified value for the height
> property of element is a <percentage>, and element does not have a
> computed value of the display property that is table-row,
> table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-cell or
> table-caption, the containing block of element must be calculated
> using the following algorithm, aborting on the first step that returns
> a value:
>
> 1. Let element be the nearest ancestor containing block of element, if
>    there is one. Otherwise, return the initial containing block.
> 2. If element has a computed value of the display property that is
>    table-cell, then return a UA-defined value.
> 3. If element has a computed value of the height property that is not
>    auto, then return element.
> 4. If element has a computed value of the position property that is
>    absolute, or if element is a not a block container or a table
>    wrapper box, then return element.
> 5. Jump to the first step.

Following this algorithm through, and taking into account the quirks rules [3.6. The html element fills the viewport quirk](https://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/#the-html-element-fills-the-viewport-quirk) and [3.7. The body element fills the html element quirk](https://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/#the-body-element-fills-the-html-element-quirk) you'll see that the 100% height of the `.box` elements is 100% of the computed height of the body element, which is 100% of the height viewport less the default margins that the body element has.

Codepen automatically adds the DOCTYPE to your mark-up, so the above quirks mode rules do not apply. Instead, the height of the `.box` elements is determined by the normal CSS rules for [percentage heights](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#x12), which states that in your case "the used height is calculated as if 'auto' was specified", and then [10.6.3 Block-level non-replaced elements in normal flow when 'overflow' computes to 'visible'](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#normal-block) which says the height is the height of the element's content.